# MissingMethodException when using FSharp.Data in Linqpad

Tags: f#, linqpad, f#-data, missingmethodexception

1. New F# Program
2. Add nuget package FSharp.Data
3. Attempt to run this code

```
open FSharp.Data

let doc = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>FSharp!</p></body></html>" |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes |> MemoryStream |> HtmlDocument.Load
CssSelectorExtensions.CssSelect (doc, "p") |> LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
```

The execution of the CssSelect function throws the error

```
Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<FSharp.Data.HtmlNode> CssSelectorExtensions.CssSelect(FSharp.Data.HtmlDocument, System.String)'.
```

Same error in both LinqPad 5 and 6.

Code runs fine in VS 2019 (without the Dump function obviously)

Can anyone repo ? Why the error in LinqPad ?

Comment: Works for me in 5.36.03.

Comment: @JimFoye do you get a MissingMethodException with this code too ? open FSharp.Data
let doc = HtmlDocument.Load("https://www.google.com")
doc.Dump()

Comment: Save the query to a file. Open the file in a text editor. At the top I would expect query kind eq FSharpProgram and NuGetReference eq FSharp.Data. If not or if more then perhaps something's wrong.

Comment: In the Samples pane, below the nuget/FSharp.Data node, see if you can get the samples to run.

Comment: @BentTranberg I owe you a Beer ! Query contents were correct. Non of the samples worked. I noticed the samples had manual references to FSharp.Core. Removed these and then added FSharp.Core from nuget. All Samples work and so does my code !!!! Errors gave no indication that the code needed FSharp.Core! So relieved i'm past the error been bashing head against wall for days.

Comment: That was actually something I considered suggesting, but didn't have much faith in it and decided to wait. Referencing or bindingRedirect to some version of FSharp.Core is often the medicine for a multitude of strange problems in LINQPad and VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding FSharp.Core from nuget to the query got rid of the error